# Is there an ML type initialization routine?

Tags: constructor, sml, smlnj, ml

Say I have a datatype that looks like

```
datatype IntLt = ltObj of int * int * (int * int -> bool)
```

That is, this object is a pair of ints with a corresponding operation on them. Is there a way to, upon the creation of an ltObj, automatically call the function with the two arguments, and raise an exception if it the result is false?

That is, I'm looking for a constructor-type procedure on datatype constructions, analogous to `__init__` in Python or usual constructors in C/C++/Java. I would prefer not to use functors and signatures for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic way to enforce such invariants in ML is by defining abstract data types (ADTs) through the module system. Here is a simple sketch:

```
signature INT_LT =
sig
  type int_lt

  val int_lt : int * int * (int * int -> bool) -> int_lt
  val pair   : int_lt -> int * int
  ... (* other abstract operations you might want *)
end

structure IntLt :> INT_LT =
struct
  type int_lt = int * int * (int * int -> bool)

  fun int_lt(x, y, f) =
      if f(x, y) then (x, y, f) else raise Domain

  fun pair(x, y, f) = (x, y)

  ...
end
```

Specifically, note the use of *opaque signature ascription* `:>` here (also known as *sealing*). It ensures that given a value of type `IntLt.int_lt` nobody can know its internal representation. That means that nobody can create values of this type without going through your module interface, nor access them.

Now, this uses signatures, but not functors. :)  (That being said, there also is a way of creating ADTs through the `abstype` construct. but it is considered deprecated in favour of sealing.)

Answer (score 1):

There is not — if you want to be able to pattern match on the constructor later.

The closest you'll come to that is to create a function that does what you desire, and use it to construct `IntLt` values:

```
exception InvalidIntLt of int * int;

fun createIntLt (a, b, f) =
    if   f(a, b)
    then LtObj (a, b, f)
    else raise InvalidIntLt (a, b);
```

Note, that it will still be valid to specify invalid* `IntLt` values by using the constructor.

If you create the datatype within a structure, you have an option to prevent this. You can hide the `LtObj` value constructor outside of the structure by using a signature. Note, however, that this also means that the value constructor cannot be used for pattern matching outside of the structure.

*: In that `f(a, b)` doesn't hold.

Comment: I do lie pattern matching... :)

Comment: @Bean, even when you encapsulate the type in a module you can still have pattern matching if that module provides a 'view' function that maps the internal type back to some externally visible type. The `pair` function in my example can be viewed as a primitive example of such a function.